VS Code: .gitignore not working for excluding ".terraform/" folders
I am trying to exclude the terraform directories and files in VS Code, using the https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Terraform.gitignore template, however it does not seem to work,it tries to upload the ".terraform/" folders too, so I get an error message that I exceed the size limit.
I have also tried to convert it via NotePad++ to Windows format using "Edit > EOL Conversion > Windows Format > Save" and also tried the following Git commands:

git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"

However, it still does not work.
I have also tried deleting the repository on GitHub and initializing it again via VS Code, but I face the same issue again and again.
Any other idea I could try?
Thank you in advance!

Did you had a look if the big files of '.terraform/' folder are already committed in last or previous commits? I that case you also have to rewrite these commits.
